I cant access my SD card, its saying "Sorry, your external storage device could not be recognized"
My external Micro SD card, SanDisk ultra, 128 GB, micro SD XC, is either saying "Sorry, at least one partition on your external storage device could not be mounted", Or "Sorry, your external storage device could not be recognized". I can access the files perfectly fine on my MP3 player and the files work but two folders that I think are the problem would not want to be deleted because how the MP3 player is.
Even using an external card reader/writer would not  load. Because I'm using a Chromebook that is managed I cannot install apps to try to restore the corrupted files. I know it has to do something with 8 Html doc type files that access IFrames and a zip file. I want to recover over 18GB of music off the Micro SD card and over 3GB of old game save data that is important.
The mp3 I'm using is this MP3 player: Aiworth MP3 Player Portable Digital Lossless Bluetooth 32 GB with TF Card Expansion, Black.
Another note is that the file manager says "This device cannot be opened because its filesystem was not recognized."
